# PHP download large file returns a 0 Kb file

Tags: php, apache

Hello fellow stakoverflowers,

I'm having a problem with PHP/Apache. I have an application that allows the admin to upload 100Mb files. The uploading works well but I'm having problems with the downloading.

It works perfectly with smaller files (tested with a 50Mb file) but for some reason I can't get the 100 Mb files.

Here's  my php code

```
$extension = 'zip'; //for testing

switch ($extension) {
  case "dwg": $contentType="image/vnd.dwg"; break;
  case "dxf": $contentType="image/vnd.dxf"; break;
  case "pdf": $contentType="application/pdf"; break;
  case "zip": $contentType="application/zip"; break; 
  case "png": $contentType="image/png"; break; 
  case "jpeg": $contentType="image/jpeg"; break; 
  case "jpg": $contentType="image/jpg"; break; 
  case "gif": $contentType="image/gif"; break; 
  default: 
    $contentType = '';
}

@header("Content-type: " . $contentType);
@header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
@header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
@header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // passed date

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

I've also tried other solutions I found on SO.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-type: " . $contentType);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($url));

echo self::url_get_contents(URL_PUBLIC . $url);

...

private function url_get_contents ($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;
    return $output;
}
```

Or

```
$file_contents = fopen($url, "r");
echo $file_contents;
fclose($file_contents);
```

All solutions return the same thing. A file size of 0 Kb.
Like I said, smaller sized files works.

Also, when I test locally, the 100 Mb size files download correctly so my guess is that the problem comes from the server. I've changed the php.ini as follows

```
register_globals = Off
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
post_max_size = 128M
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
max_execution_time = 120
expose_php = off
session.save_path = /tmp
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql5.sock
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql5.sock
```

It's probably a memory limit problem but not sure.

Comment: Is the $url variable in the first example a URL with http:// in front or a path like /home/yoursite?

Comment: Do you have a share hosting? Couldn't they be limiting it? (since it works locally?)

Comment: My bet it is due to the hosting limitations. Time limit would end in a PHP error not even downloading a 0 byte file...

Comment: @drew010 Depending on the solution I tried I used the correct path to the URL (http:// and /home/yoursite). I don't think that's the problem but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Trufa My thoughts exactly. I will contact the support.

Comment: @ComputerArts great! Good luck, please update us if it turned to be that or not.

Comment: @Trufa Yep, you guys are right. This is the answer I got: "It seems that the application is hitting the memory limit on your hosting account. We are forwarding this ticket to our system administrators, who will check if this limit can be increased." Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem before. My problem turned out to be the hosting provider. Once a script takes too long to execute, the hosting provider typically just shuts it off. I've had the same issues when trying to upload large sql scripts through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I've had the exact same problem and changing hosting providers cured it too.

Comment: For anyone interested, the memory limit was set to 195M and then they increased it to 295M. Even though I had changed the php.ini, my value was not taken in consideration.

Comment: @vyx.ca If you're still having the same problem, my hosting provider told me to create a `PHP.ini` file and place it in my `cgi-bin` folder. From there, I was able to override any default settings. You might have had a `max_execution_time` issue, as I did as well.

Comment: @Fred Thanks. I already tried that. I don't have the problem anymore. The hosting provider had a fixed limit even though I had changed it in the php.ini file. I had to ask them to change it and they did for one specific site.

Comment: @vyx.ca Welcome. Glad it worked out then. Only thing though, kind of a pain having to contact them each time a problem may arise, (neighbour) ;)

Comment: @Fred the suspense is killing me... I know only a couple of Fred but which one are you? :)

Comment: @vyx.ca By the looks of your website, we're in the same sector. Too bad you didn't have a contact form, I'd of sent you a message.